# Air Resistance Effects on a Potato, a Dirt Clod, and a Rock

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, drag

Let me preface this by saying that I know little to nothing about physics, so I understand any personal attacks on my intelligence and gladly accept them so long as I learn something.

Having said that, can anyone tell me what effect blowing air would have on a potato, a dirt clod, and a rock, given that they are all of similar size? Obviously they type of potato, dirt clod, and rock could vary and thus, the calculation could vary, but I'm not looking for a high degree of accuracy here.

So for example, if I had 3 tubes, one containing a potato, one containing a rock, and one containing a dirt clod, then blew enough air through the tubes to suspend the potato, and matched that volume in the other tubes, what would the dirt clod and rock do? My suspicion is that the dirt clod would suspend at a similar height while the rock would suspend much lower or not at all. Something tells me that terminal velocity has something to do with this, but refer to the lack-of-physics-intelligence paragraph above to find out why I don't know that for sure.

Comment: -1. Not clear what you are asking. If they are all the same size and shape, then what difference is there between them? The only difference left is mass, and it must be obvious that, other things being equal, the heavier object reaches the higher terminal velocity. (But which is the heavier object is not obvious.) If you are asking about some other difference between them, what is it?

Comment: So in potato farming, the problematic dirt clods brought up from the ground tend to be the same size and mass as the potatoes, so using air as a medium to attempt to separate the potatoes and clods is not ideal because the potatoes and clods are close enough in size that the air moves them both. Air works great for moving potatoes out of rocks for obvious reasons, but the clods always come with the potatoes. I'm essentially wondering what physical principles are at play here and can it be calculated and how?

Comment: We are attempting to utilize different physical principles to separate these three things more accurately. Water is ideal for separation, but does not bode well for the quality of the potatoes in the long term, so our idea is to fluidize a medium such as sand to make it act like water. It has been done in the past, but I am trying to be able to explain in layman's terms why air is not the solution for separating potatoes and dirt clods.

Comment: In physics we deal with [spherical cows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cow). We can predict how ideal objects will behave, but not real objects like potatoes, clods and stones. These objects are too variable, too difficult to predict (except in ideal, controlled conditions). Theoretical physics cannot reliably show you that the method will or won't work. For that you have to do experiments. There is only one equation in Zaltzmann's Fluidized Bed research paper (1983), and it has no effect at all on the results, which were obtained by experimenting with a mechanical apparatus.

Comment: I completely understand that and can tell you that I have plenty of practical experience with this. Air will not separate dirt clods from potatoes. I work for  a potato equipment manufacturer and we have seen this in practice many times. I guess what I am getting at is an intelligent explanation as to why the air is not a useful medium to remove clods. I'm looking for someone to explain the physical principles behind what is happening. Is it terminal velocity? Is it density? Is it that the drag force of a potato and a dirt clod are roughly the same, while a rock's is much larger?

Comment: One machine that has worked well is called a sand machine, which separates materials according to specific gravities. Basically, a conveyor belt moves product into a bed of sand that has been fluidized with air. Once calibrated just right, the potatoes, rocks, and clods will all take a different path through the sand and end up on different conveyor belts. It has been the most successful separating apparatus known to the industry. It sounds similar to what Zaltzmann researched. It would be nice to know the principles involved in that process as well if you know them

Comment: The actual drag force is the same (for the same size of object, same fluid speed, etc.)  The *acceleration* of the object, however, is determined by the mass of the object.  The potato and clod are accelerated by roughly the same amount, while the rock, having more mass, is accelerated less.

Comment: Alright, so drag force could be the same if the potato, rock, and dirt clod are exactly the same, but the acceleration of the each object will depend on its mass.

Comment: Yes.  Newton's Second Law at work in this one.

Answer (score 0):

Fluid moving past an object will exert a drag force that, all other factors being equal, depends on the cross-sectional area of the object.  If all three objects are roughly the same size, then the drag force itself will be roughly the same for each.

Suspending an object, however, depends on more than the drag force: the mass of the object being suspended is important!  In a suspended object, the upward drag force must balance the downward-directed weight of the object.  A heavier object will require a larger drag force than a lighter one to suspend it (assuming the sizes of the objects are the same.)  Increasing the speed of the fluid will increase the drag force, so a heavier object requires a faster moving fluid for suspension.

Comment: So if the fluid in question (i.e. the air moving through the tubes) was delivered at exactly the same volume and speed, would the effect on the potato be roughly that of the effect on the dirt clod? So if I want to remove potatoes from a mix of potatoes, rocks, and dirt clods by using air, it is an effort made in vain because the dirt clods and potatoes will be affected roughly the same by the fluid. It would basically take both the potatoes and clods out of the stream and leave the rocks, correct?

Comment: Assuming that the mass of the rocks was the highest of the three, yes.  This changes if the objects fit snugly within the tube - that's a potato gun.

Comment: So I should have explained this upfront, but I have quite a bit of practical experience with air separation of rocks, clods, and potatoes. I can tell you that air (either a vacuum or blowing from underneath) is not the answer to the separation question. Air works on separating potatoes from rocks, but not from dirt clods. I guess my real question is what are the physical principles at play here so I can explain in layman's terms why air is not the answer? Is it because the drag force of the potato and dirt clod are likely to be similar, while the rock's drag force is much higher?